# Virtual machine Windows 10 unmountable boot volume error

Tags: windows-10, boot, virtual-machine, bsod, linux-kvm

I'm running Windows 10 through KVM and `virt-manager`. Today, I'm receiving a BSoD along with error:

> Unmountable boot volume

[image: BSoD error]

Then, the screen shows automatic repair preparation:

[image: Automatic repair]

Then, a black screen is shown without any observable activity. I ran out of options. Do you have any idea what might be wrong with the VM?

## Update

Some observations are here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/681522/158683

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Conclusion

I will have to back up the data and replace the hard disk:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/683313/158683

## Tried

I tried to handle the bad blocks of the hard disk by this:

```bsh
badblocks -svn /dev/sda
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/683310/158683